# Collapse part of items in a list

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I'd like to create a list of webradio stations using JQuery Mobile. Parts of the list (like the stations name and the genre tags) should be permanently visible, while other parts (like the url or comments) should be collapsed and only get uncollapsed on demand.

To clarify my requirements I made an example:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
            <h2>Item 1</h2>
            <div class="tag-list">
                <span class="tag">Tag A</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-list">
                <div class="comment">
                    <p>This is a comment</p>
                </div>
                <div class="comment">
                    <p>Another comment</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(better viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/uAvpS/1/)

Only `comment-list` and `comment` should be collapsed, the rest should always be visible.

How can this be achieved? In my point of view this is different to [collapsible lists](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/uAvpS/3/

Comment: almost! I'd like the whole <li> object to be collapsible. Collapsed only the main information should be visible (like the name and the genres). When uncollapsed, every information should be visible (like the url and the comments. Thank you!

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uAvpS/4/

Comment: yes! If you formulate an anser I could accept it. Great work!

Comment: Glad it sorbed for You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each `li` a `data-role="collapsible"` and inside its' header, add your custom `span` which hold tags.

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pyLJv/)

```
<li data-role="collapsible">
  <h2>Item 1<span class="tag-list"><span class="tag">tag 1</span></span></h2>
  <div class="comment">
    <p>This is a comment</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    <p>Another comment</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: thank you! I just want to add, it does only work with `<div>`s inside of the header element.

Comment: oh sorry, I wanted to write >>also<< not >>only<< my bad! Thank you once again!

Comment: @speendo welcome buddy. I have updated the demo if you want to have a look :)

Comment: wow, that looks neat... do you have an idea how one could merge the outer part of each item with the inner part (the one with the +button)? In my oppinion the inner part looks somehow lost... I know this is a different question, so no need to answer that ;)

Comment: @speendo you mean filling `li` with collapsible button?

Comment: yes, filling the `li` with the collapsible button (just repeating to get the min characters ;-) )